# How to debug chained executables in Visual Studio solution

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have two projects in VS2015. The executable from start up project at some point needs to open the output executable from the second project. (by using Process.Start)

How can I debug the second executable as well as the main one? Can VS include the second executable in the output directory and setup debugging automatically?

Comment: There is no such thing as an *"executable from the entry project"*. Did you mean to say *"Startup project"* instead? And what is *"calling an executable"* supposed to mean? This doesn't make much sense. Please exercise a bit more care when asking questions, and update this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either attach the debugger manually after the second process started (using Debug -> Attach to process) or use the [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a)